# How to reuse file value in Kotlin / Android app

Tags: android, kotlin

**Super** new to Kotlin, literally day 1. I know python, c#, NodeJS, but no Java / Kotlin.

I'm trying to build an example app that does 3 things:

- `btn1` to select an image from the gallery (got that)
- show the image to the user (got that as well)
- `btn2` to upload said image to an API (got this partially)

I've got the scaffolding for step 3, however, I'm missing the reference to the image picked in step 1.
`btn1` executes this:

```
private fun pickImageFromGallery() {
        //Intent to pick image
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
        intent.type = "image/*"
        startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_PICK_CODE)
    }

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == IMAGE_PICK_CODE){
            image_view.setImageURI(data?.data)
        }
    }
```

I now don't understand how I can use the reference to the image when the user clicks on `btn2`, seeing that the reference is passed to `onActivityResult` as the `data` object which seems to not be available to `btn2`.

Most of this code is copy&paste until it works, and the first two steps work well now.

Any tips?

Thanks!

Comment: Store the `Uri` in a property somewhere (ideally in a viewmodel, or in the short term in the activity or fragment where this code resides). Note that your question title uses the word "file", but the user is picking a piece of content, which may or may not be a file. Also note that you are not using `ACTION_PICK` correctly. `ACTION_PICK` is for picking from a collection (which you are not specifying). `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` and `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` are for selecting based on MIME type.